# how can i Extract JSON from HTTP Response (python)

Tags: python, json, lambda, http-headers, httprequest

i get this from lambda api gateway. how can i get {\n "a":"b",\n "c":"d",\n "e":"f",\n "g":"h"\n} to json style ?

```
"------WebKitFormBoundarySfqiG2UABUZYF7Ir\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"upload-file\"; 
filename=\"example.json\"\r\n
Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n
{\n \"a\":\"b\",\n \"c\":\"d\",\n \"e\":\"f\",\n \"g\":\"h\"\n}
\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySfqiG2UABUZYF7Ir--"
```

i want make this
{\n "a":"b",\n "c":"d",\n "e":"f",\n "g":"h"\n}

to

```
{
  "a":"b",
  "c":"d",
  "e":"f",
  "g":"h"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you handle a response to get this?

Try this

```
import json
result = json.loads(x[x.find('{'): x.find('}')+1])
```

x is your string

Comment: i get this from  event['body-json'] . i will try it

Comment: I update code , it not a best way but could work.